# Using jQuery, add class "subtle" to all <span> tags that descend from a <h1> tag

Tags: javascript

My problem is I don't understand how to choose span after I have selected h1 or how I would descend it at all

This is what i've tried, $("h:span").addClass("subtle"); and i'm not quite sure how far off I am

the html:

```
<h1><span>Header</span> 1</h1>
<h2><span>Header</span> 2</h2>
<h3><span>Header</span> 3</h3>
<p><span>Section</span> content</p>
<ol>
   <li><span>First</span> item</li>
   <li><span>Second</span> item</li>
   <li><span>Third</span> item</li>
</ol>
```

Comment: Questions seeking debugging help ("why isn't this code working?") must include the desired behavior, a specific problem or error and the shortest code necessary to reproduce it in the question itself.

Comment: what is the meaning of 'h:span'? You said you wanted to track all the `span` where parent is h1

Comment: This question needs work to be answerable. [Please follow this guide to create a Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example.](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Setting aside the objections just raised about your question, it seems clear enough that I can answer.  Your jQuery is just adding "subtle" to the h1's themselves.  You need to use $("h1 span").addClass("subtle") and that should take care of it.  That's "h1", then a space, then "span".

There are a wide variety of resources available to explain this "selector" syntax in detail, including those at jQuery's own site, and a 'jquery phrasebook' I learned some from, a while back.  It's best to take the time to learn them as a separate topic.

Comment: Ah thank you very much, that's exactly what I was looking for and I will take your advice as well and look into the selector syntax's.

Comment: Glad I could help.  Since your question is resolved, please mark my response as answer here, it's a StackOverflow thing.  Happy coding.